# Moderator Pro Tempore blog has a wrong link!

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, blog

In https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/, it says:

> Of course, if the idea involves the core engine or applies to a broader range of sites, the idea should be raised in [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/): the “capital city” of Stack Exchange.

Please update the link to MSE instead of MSO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link has been updated.

<kbd>[image: Corrected link]</kbd>

Comment: ... as Shog9 stated by adding [status-completed]. But now looks like that was you who fixed it :)

Comment: No more than saying "X has been killed" is an admission of murder.

Comment: @nic I was so confused, I had to verify [who fixed it :P](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2659365#2659365)